# Showing feature label in Layout Legend using QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling, legend

I am using QGIS 3.18.2.

I have a polygon layer, with labels, as in the following image.

[image]

When I create a layout, the legend contains the layers feature, but no label, as in the following image.

[image]

How do I display the label, either automatically (i.e. auto update checked), or manually create a similar label?

Comment: In the layout use the add shapes and texts tools to recreate the rectangle, text, line and label symbol.  For the label use the the add marker and configure it; for the line you could add an arrow and configure that to get rid of the arrowhead.  You could try to add just the line and label symbol equivalents to an inserted legend containing the polygon symbol and feature name but note if you adjust your legend you would then have to adjust the location of these other items.

Comment: Thanks Johns. But,wow, I'm surprised such basic cartographic functionality is missing.

Answer (score 0):

In QGIS 3.28.5

[See Manual here](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html#legend-properties)

**TLDR...**

Go to [Layer Properties][Legend]

Turn on [Show Label Legend]

[image]